# Search tool using keywords on Excel data or a keyword based corresponding code and description search : The file needs permission

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

I am a basic level Excel user. I need some help on preparing a look-up tool using keywords as described below:

I have a list of 1000 different product/service descriptions along with their respective internal codes, which correspondingly have sub-codes and sub-categories.  Each category has multiple keywords or may be 7 to 8 keywords. I need the users to get the sub-codes, categories and sub-categories as defined and associated with their respective keywords search.

[image: Trial sheet of excel saved as an image file for reference]
 <sup>**Trial Excel spreadsheet**  (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Apologies, as I had something that came up which was as good as an emergency, hence delay in sharing the file.  I have shared the link where I have uploaded the file. Kindly have a check and advise.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7y54phakclf1ha/Trial%20Sheet%20for%20look-up%20tool.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Upload the file to a file sharing site, there are plenty of free ones, then post a link to the file on that site.

Comment: That's a tall ask. It looks like keywords appear in multiple rows. What would you expect if somebody enters "Import & Export", which is in row 9 and also in row 14 of the visible data, and probably exists many more times? What about "Information Technology" versus "Information Technology & Sciences" - When someone types "information technology" - what would you expect?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.  In fact, we need the Import & export which is the keyword for two components to come up showing both the lines of data. A few words would appear in multiple tasks, which I need to show-up with those all available options for that particular keyword. And with regards to the Information technology v/s Info Tech & Sciences, I guess it could be changed to Information Tech on both the occasions, the the user finds both these entries show-up. Your assistance is much appreciated. - Suresh

Comment: Uploaded the link for the shared file. Request assistance : https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7y54phakclf1ha/Trial%20Sheet%20for%20look-up%20tool.xlsx?dl=0